# Work done by force on block against gravity and friction up irregular rough incline?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, energy-conservation, friction, work

[image]

I recently found a question which I think is from Irodov which asked about the work done by a force $F$ on a body of mass $M$ up a rough hill. At each point in the path of the body the force is tangential to to the hill. Now in the solution to this question, it is eventually proven that the work done by the force $F$ is $\mu mgx + mgy$, hence proving that the path trajectory does not matter in the net work done.

The work done against friction is found to be $\mu mgx $ through integration of the work done against friction $\mu mg\cosθ\,{\rm d}l$ where ${\rm d}l$ is a minute distance travelled by the body and $\mu mg\cosθ$ gives the normal force and I understood the method.

However all this while I have learnt that work done by a non-conservative force such as friction depends on the path traversed. Is that incorrect? Or if it is correct and applied only to certain cases, what cases is it applied to? What has gone wrong in my understanding?

Comment: Work done by friction is of course path dependent. ... The term $x$ in the work done by friction indicates so ...

Comment: In this example only a motion straight up the slope is to be considered.

Comment: The work done here just depends on the distance travelled in the x direction, but it does not matter how bumpy the incline is. However in many books it says that while conservative forces like gravity are path independent, friction depends on the route taken. So I am confused.

Comment: @Farcher motion straight up the slope meaning?

Comment: What do you mean by $x$ and $y$ ?

Comment: x is the distance travelled along the x axis and y distance along y axis or height, the hill itself is an incline with a bumpy surface, I'll add an image in the question.

Comment: @NehalSamee Just because a variable appears in the equation does not make it path dependent. This would then mean that the work done by gravity is path dependent. The question is referring to the observation that the work just depends on the end points of the path rather than the actual path taken, which is a property of conservative forces.

Comment: @AaronStevens ... I think there is no variable ( which I thought $x$ to be ) ... I later on understood the integration  of $dW=\mu mgdlcos\theta +mg dl sin\theta$ ...

Comment: @Hema ... Nothing is wrong with your understanding ... As gravity is a conservative force , the work done is dependent only on initial and final positions.  And for friction , you have considered the path taken . If the incline was plane , work done by friction would be $\mu mgl$ ...

Comment: @NehalSamee if the incline was a plane the work would not be what you say it is. You forgot that the normal force is not just mg.

Comment: @AaronStevens ...Oops ... Can't edit ... It should be $\mu mgcos\theta .l$ ...

Comment: @NehalSamee Exactly! :) and then we get μmgx like before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the force is tangential to the hill, and the hill is bumpy, the force must be constantly changing direction, and it is changing direction *based on the path*.

So this is not a case in which there is a particular non-conservative force, and several different paths that have the same work. This is a case where there are different paths, and a *different force* for each one.

That said, it *is* possible for a fixed non-conservative force to have multiple paths that have the same work. Non-conservative just means that given a particular path, there is *some* path with a different work, not that *all* paths have a different work.

Note that if you reverse this path, then the sign of the gravitational work will be reversed, while the friction work will remain the same. Thus, simply taking the reverse path results in a different amount of work. Also, if the object were moved in two different horizontal direction, then the work would increase. If the object were moved along switch-backs (moving back and forth in the x direction while increasing y position), then the work would be based on the total distance traveled, rather than the displacement.